# NAOqi Simulator SDK

Tags: simulator, nao-robot

I am relatively new to working with Nao Robots. As part of many guthub repositories, simulator sdk packages are needed for code to work. I am unable to find those. If they are deprecated,  what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Simulator and that Simulator SDK to work with a robot.
If you need a complete simulator environment running NAOqi, try Webots. If you  use ROS, Gazebo should work too.